# Multiplication table in a msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I need to show on the same `MsgBox` the multiplication table of a number chosen by a user.

```
Sub Multiplication1()

    Dim number As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim res As Integer

    number = InputBox(" Write number ")

    For i = 1 To 10
        res = number * i

        MsgBox (number & " *" & i & " =" & res & vbCrLf)
    Next

End Sub
```

In this code, for every loop iteration I have a now `MsgBox` with the correct answer, I want all the answers on the same msgbox.

Comment: Build the string inside the loop and move the `MsgBox` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few remarks: don't use `Integer`, it's stored as `Long` anyway in VBA and you don't need to declare all variables on separate lines :) see the code below. And to sdolve your problem, append every result to a string variable in a loop, after that display it in a message box.

```
Sub Multiplication1()
    Dim number As Long, i As Long, res As Long, s As String
    number = InputBox(" Write number ")
    s = ""
    For i = 1 To 10
        res = number * i
        s = s & (number & " *" & i & " =" & res & vbCrLf)
    Next

    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: @AbdelmalekAissi If my answer helped you you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate one string with the table, *before* display the message box:

```
Sub Multiplication1()

Dim number As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim res As Integer
Dim myTable as String


number = InputBox(" Write number ")

For i = 1 To 10
    res = number * i
    myTable = myTable & number & " *" & i & " =" & res & vbCrLf
Next i

MsgBox myTable

End Sub
```

Comment: I wish you actually let me find the correct way of writing it :) , however, thank you so much for your help !